# Trigger event in openjpa when row changes in database

Tags: java, spring, jpa, openjpa

Is it possible to get an event from OpenJPA when a row is updated in the database?
I cannot use the `@PostUpdate` annotation as the database is updated outside the JVM that wants this event.

We are using OpenJPA and an Oracle database.

Comment: I don't know about OpenJPA, but you can with EclipseLink: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/DatabaseEvents

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get an event from OpenJPA when a row is updated in the database?

No it is not without a bunch of work. You could implement your own [database change listener](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815) and plug it into the OpenJPA runtime. What do you want OpenJPA to do when the database gets updated?

Comment: I have two applications running in different jvms. They are not allowed to contact each other in any way due to infrastructure limitations. The only thing they have in common is the database. What I want is that when some row in the database gets a specific value the other app picks up that row and does some computations. I can of course do polling, but that is not the way I want it.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Yes, checkout implementing a change listener. If you come up with something, please post to the OpenJPA users mailing list. Others might be interested in hearing what you did.